# Differentiable functions and examples

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

can someone give me an example of Differentiable function at x=4 and funcstions who dont Differentiable function at x=4?

$f(x) = 2x-7$

$k(x) = 100x^7-55x^5+10000x^2$

$g(x) = 23$

Those are Differentiable function at x-4, right?

$q(x) = x/(x-4)$

$y(x) = 78x^2/(x^2-8x+16)$

$p(x) = 2/(x^2+16)$

and those are not Differentiable function?

Am I right?

Thanks for help

Comment: Furthermore, $q, y$ and $p$ are not continous at $x=4$. Maybe you are looking for something more like $h(x) = |x-4|$, where $| x |$ is the absolute value function. In this case, $h$ is continous but not differentiable at $x=4$. Another example would be $r(x) = \sqrt{x-4}$. Cheers!

Comment: @Dmoreno. What is the problem with $p(x)$ ?

Comment: Hi @ClaudeLeibovici, there's no problem at all. I just missinterpreted $p(x) = 2/(x^2 - 16)$. My fault!

Comment: @Dmoreno 0 so the examples that I gave are fine? why r(x) is bot diff' at x-4? there's no function the isn't continous but is diff', right?

Comment: @Dmoreno please help

Comment: Hi @momd. Precisely, there are no differentiable and not continous functions since continuity is a necessary condition for differentiability. Regarding $r(x)$, what is the derivative of $\sqrt{x}$? And what is then the limit of $r'(x)$ as $x \to 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first three examples that you provide are differentiable at $x=4$ and that's because they are polynomials and on $\mathbb{R}$ all polynomials are differentiable.

Also, you can check if a function is differentiable at $a$ if, simply, $f'(a)$ exists or if it has one of the following:

1. Vertical Tangent
2. Discontiunity
3. A corner like $\vee$ or $\wedge$

So, here the derivatives of your last three functions:

$$q'(x) = \frac{4}{(x-4)^2}$$
$$y'(x) = \frac{-624x}{(x-4)^3}$$
$$p'(x) = \frac{-4x}{(x^2+16)^2}$$

If you sub in $x=4$ here then you can find out which are not differentiable at $x=4$ and which are (hint: $p(x)$ but why and not simply because $f'(a)$ exists)

Comment: $x/(x-3)$ is also diff and $x=4$? and I didn't understand - so p(x) is diff or not?

Comment: If $f'(a)$ exists then $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x = a$. So, notice the derivatives I gave you. Plug $x = 4$ into them. Which of those derivatives will come undefined and which will not? The ones that _do not_ come undefined i.e. $p(x)$ can be differentiated at $x = 4$. That being said, notice that $p(x)$ is always negative and does not fulfill any of the conditions I listed above.